# Gridview display field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a date field that I display in a column in my gridview, in an ASP.Net app. However, there is a boolean field, that when set, the date is irrelevant (It's actually a nullable date, and will be null)

When the boolean field is set, (and therefore, the date is null), I see a blank column. But, I'd prefer to display some custom text instead. So, is there a way to display the date, when the flag is false, and if it's true, display "No date set" in the column instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by placing check in RowDataBound event and set the text property of cell to desired text.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(condition is true)
            e.Row.Cells[index of date field column].Text = "Date not set";
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to this - How do you check the record that is being applied to the row? What I mean is, how do I check if the record that caused the new row to be added - how do I check a property of that record. Example, I populate from List<PersonObject>, showing Firstname and Surname, as well as age. The PersonObject may have an Age property, and if Age = -1, I was to show "Age Unknown", else, the age. How do I check that propery?

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
           PersonObject person= (PersonObject)e.Row.DataItem;
           if (person.Age == -1)
           {
               e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Date not set";
           }
        }. e.Row.DataItem property will give us the object that has binded to the row. so we can easily cast that object back to the type we actually have in data souce.